# Is Holy Surge Strictly Better (and less expensive) than Holy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

The DMG (p225) has the **Holy** enchantment listed as costing a +2 enchantment.

The MIC (p36) has the **Holy Surge** enchantment as costing just a +1 enchantment, and says:

> A holy surge weapon functions as a holy weapon (DMG 225). In addition... (it does other cool stuff)

Am I correct in reading that **Holy Surge** costs less than **Holy** and does more?  If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found my answer on Page 27 of the MIC.  It specifies that enchantments with the **synergy** keyword have another enchantment as a pre-requisite.

So it looks like you have to first have Holy on the weapon before putting Holy Surge on it, making the total cost for both enchantments +3.

Comment: I believe that all of the "surge" weapons are this way. [citation needed]